# testing the presence of form elements via rspec on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, testing, rspec

Hey all,
I am having trouble testing the presence of form elements on my ruby on rails view. I am using rspec and have_selector to test.

Here is my test code:

```
it "should always have like button for root entity" do
  get :index
  @entities[0..3].each do |entity|
    response.should have_selector("form", 
      :method => "post", :action => "like/#{entity[:id]}") do |form|
        form.should have_selector("input", :value => "Like")
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my view's output for a particular entity:

```
    <th>
      <form method="post" action="/like/1"  class="button_to">
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Like" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="WEJPdFzphPFz+ld6BO8c/sMlhdfm+2Trp+3n0J8H5Cs=" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </th>
```

Here is my rspec error:

> 1) EntitiesController GET 'index'
>   entities exist for non-signed in users
>   should always have like button for
>   root entity
>        Failure/Error: form.should have_selector("input", :value =>
>   "Like")
>        expected following output to contain a < input value='Like'/> tag.

If I comment out the line "form.should have_selector("input", :value => "Like")" so the test code is:

```
it "should always have like button for root entity" do
  get :index
  @entities[0..3].each do |entity|
    response.should have_selector("form", 
      :method => "post", :action => "like/#{entity[:id]}") do |form|
        #form.should have_selector("input", :value => "Like")
    end
  end
end
```

My rspec error is:

> 1) EntitiesController GET 'index'
>   entities exist for non-signed in users
>   should always have like button for
>   root entity
>        Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("form",
>        expected following output to contain a < form method='post'
>   action='like/2127'/> tag:
>
> < form method="post"
>   action="/like/2127"
>   class="button_to">< div>< input
>   type="submit"
>   value="Like">

(only relevant part is c/ped)

I seem to be facing a lot of trouble with have_selector when it comes to form elements. Is there a better alternative or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Guys, can anyone help with this? Still cant seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your form's action is

```
action="/like/1"
```

but you're searching for

```
action="like/1"
```

i.e. you're missing a slash.

Comment: In other words, your tests are extremely brittle and suspect to breakage from the most tiny of changes, like URL paths.